# Do I need an ASV to come out when going for an SAQ?

Tags: penetration-test, pci-dss, vulnerability-scanners, nessus

Our company is going for a SAQ, under PCI DSS 3.1.

Do we need to pay a vendor to come out and do an on site scan, or can we use something like Nessus to do the scan on our own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the external scan requires an ASV:

[PCI 3.1 states](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/security_standards/documents.php?agreements=pcidss&association=pcidss#leadgendiv):

> 11.2.2 Perform quarterly external vulnerability scans, via an Approved Scanning Vendor (ASV) approved by the Payment Card Industry Security
>   Standards Council (PCI SSC). Perform rescans as needed, until passing
>   scans are achieved.

It is only on internal scans where you can run a tool such as Nessus (**em** mine):

> 11.2.1 Perform quarterly internal vulnerability scans and rescans as needed, until all “high-risk” vulnerabilities (as identified in
>   Requirement 6.1) are resolved. Scans must be performed by qualified
>   personnel.
>
> verify that the scan was performed by a qualified internal resource(s)
>   or qualified external third party, and if applicable, organizational
>   independence of the tester exists **(not required to be a QSA or ASV)**

The external test does not require anyone "coming out". You can simply use an automated service such as [Hacker Guardian](https://www.hackerguardian.com/hackerguardian/buy/pci-free-scan.html) which will satisfy the scan being done by an ASV.

Comment: This answer still applicable in 2020?

Comment: Yes, this hasn't changed in the latest version of the standard, v3.2.1

Answer (score 0):

To quote [PCI DSS 3.1](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI_DSS_v3-1.pdf) section 11.2:

> There are three types of vulnerability scanning required for PCI DSS:
>
> - Internal quarterly vulnerability scanning by qualified personnel (use of a PCI SSC Approved Scanning Vendor (ASV) is not required)
> - External quarterly vulnerability scanning, which must be performed by an ASV
> - Internal and external scanning as needed after significant changes

So **you need an ASV for your external scans**, but **you can do it yourself for internal scans**.  If you are audited by a QSA, instead of filling out the SAQ yourself, expect that they will ask for evidence that the person performing the scans is qualified - you can't have Bob in Accounting do it unless he's got something on his resume that indicates he knows something about Security.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what kind of scan you're looking at. Since you've mentioned that your company is doing an SAQ (https://www.hackerguardian.com/pci-saq.html), I'm guessing it's going to be an internal audit. Like SilverlightFox and gowenfawr have suggested, doing it internally just requires an in-house expert to ensure things are PCI compliant.

A company I worked for few years ago used HackerGuardian (https://www.hackerguardian.com/) to fill the external scanning requirement instead of hiring a third-party ASV.